# How to select random rows using limit and some sort of score?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to make a sql query where I have several rows. It is only within the same table.

The result (1 or more rows) has to be random and following a point system from 0 to ... (any large number like 5000).

From this data dump, for example, I would like to select X names randomly and following the points.

The result from selecting 3 rows could be ids:

10, 6 and 4

OR 6, 10, 4

If it is 4 rows, the result would be:

10, 6, 4, 9

OR

6, 10, 4, 9

```
CREATE TABLE `draw` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`points` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `draw` (`id`, `name`, `points`) VALUES (1, 'a', '65');
INSERT INTO `draw` (`id`, `name`, `points`) VALUES (2, 'b', '5000');
INSERT INTO `draw` (`id`, `name`, `points`) VALUES (3, 'c', '900');
INSERT INTO `draw` (`id`, `name`, `points`) VALUES (4, 'd', '10');
INSERT INTO `draw` (`id`, `name`, `points`) VALUES (5, 'e', '1000');
INSERT INTO `draw` (`id`, `name`, `points`) VALUES (6, 'f', '0');
INSERT INTO `draw` (`id`, `name`, `points`) VALUES (7, 'g', '650');
INSERT INTO `draw` (`id`, `name`, `points`) VALUES (8, 'h', '600');
INSERT INTO `draw` (`id`, `name`, `points`) VALUES (9, 'i', 30');
INSERT INTO `draw` (`id`, `name`, `points`) VALUES (10, 'j', '0');
```

Comment: "randomly" sound like a conflict with "following the points". What is the definition of "following the points"?

Comment: get rows randomly ordered by points 0 to 5000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `SELECT` the rows based on points first, and then make a selection from that result with random order by using it as a subquery. To ensure that we don't always select the same user if more than one has the same points, we also order the subquery by `RAND()` *after* `points`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM draw
      ORDER BY points, RAND()
      LIMIT 4) d
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Output:

```
id  name    points
9   i       30
10  j       0
6   f       0
4   d       10
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uHeG6vGhMLLXo3EBPisRtS/0)

Comment: I just noticed that if i have more people with the same points, example 10, it gets always the same row.

Comment: @RenanAguiar I see what you mean, I'll edit the query

Comment: @RenanAguiar Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: my local is: Server version: 5.6.28

Comment: @RenanAguiar see my edit. It solves the problem by adding a secondary ordering by `RAND()` to the subquery.

Comment: it seems to be a 100%! thank you! I was think in recursive on php